# spacemacs ess knitr doesn't work with Rmd files

Tags: r, ess, spacemacs

I really want to switch from RStudio to Spacemacs with ess layer. However I can't get it to work. I have the following in my dotfile:

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
 '(
   html

 ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
 ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
 ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
 ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
 ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
 markdown
 helm
 ess
 auto-completion
 better-defaults
 emacs-lisp
 git
 polymode
 mu4e
 ;; markdown
 ;; (shell :variables
 org 
 ;;        shell-default-height 30
 ;;        shell-default-position 'bottom)
 spell-checking
 syntax-checking
 ;; version-control
 )
```

I have the following packages.el in my .emacs.d private folder copied with thanks from github.

```
;;; packages.el --- polymode layer packages file for Spacemacs.
;;
;; Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Sylvain Benner & Contributors
;;
;; Author: Walmes Zeviani & Fernando Mayer
;; URL: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs

;;; Code:

(defconst polymode-packages
 '(polymode))

(defun polymode/init-polymode () 
  (use-package polymode
    :mode (("\\.Rmd"   . Rmd-mode))
    :init
    (progn
      (defun Rmd-mode ()
    "ESS Markdown mode for Rmd files"
    (interactive)
    (require 'poly-R)
    (require 'poly-markdown)
    (R-mode)
    (poly-markdown+r-mode))
  ))
  )

;;; packages.el ends here
```

Syntax highlighting and code completeion etc are working fine but if I try and send code chunks to REPL i get 'wrong type argument stringp nil' error with both Rmd and Rmv files.

emacs 25.2.1 with spacemacs

fresh install on both mac and linux with no other config loaded. Own .emacs has been deleted

some functions seem to work but not like they should e.g. eval-buffer will just send the current code chunk to REPL

Very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit tricky to me to make it works with Rmd. Have you try with a simple .R file to see if it works?

This is what I currently have in mi .emacs file for the Rmd files

```
;; MARKDOWN
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md" . poly-markdown-mode))

;; R modes
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Snw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode))

;; polymode
(setq load-path (append '("/home/fer/.emacs.d/elpa/polymode-20170307.322"
"/home/farce/.emacs.d/polymode/modes") load-path))

(require 'poly-R)
(require 'poly-markdown)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
```